# Mount external hard drive in virtualbox

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox

I have virtualbox 4.3.12 extension pack installed on a windows 7 computer and am running a virtual machine with Ubuntu 12.04 on it. I have an external hard drive that I would like to access within the virtual machine but whenever I have it plugged in and the virtual machine is turned on, it seems to just unmount the hard drive from windows and not show it in Ubuntu. I have tried adding the USB device filter in virtualbox and the hard drive is listed under devices but still doesn't show up in the virtual machine. I have also tried unmounting it from windows before starting the virtual machine.  Nothing seems to work.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the Guest Additions?

Comment: If you haven't already, [install Guest Additions for Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm).

Comment: YMMV, but I just verified that I can mount USB drives in a Lubuntu guest that does not have guest additions installed. Are you making sure to select your external drive in Devices > USB Devices?

Comment: I have it selected in Devices but there doesn't seem to be an option to install guest additions.